# Update ArrayList by passing argument in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am trying to up create and update an `ArrayList` by passing an argument, so that I will end up with a list of say 10 names; however, the current function doesn't seem to be working - any ideas pls?

```
   public String addClient(String name) {
     ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
     myList.add(name);

     return myList;
   }
```

Comment: `public String addClient(String name)` must return a `String`, not a `List<>`.

Comment: You have a method having return type `String` and you are returning `ArrayList`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a `new ArrayList` every time you call it.  This means that every time you call this method you create a brand new Collection and only store the one client in it.  You need to keep a reference of a single collection around and keep adding to that.  You can do that by passing in the array you want to add it to:

```
public List<String> addClient(String name, List<String> array) {
    array.add(name);
    return array;
}
```

This doesn't seem like a useful function, so I'm guessing this is within a class.  So this might be the approach you want:

```
/**
 * Class is not Thread Safe
 */
public class ClientList {
    private final ArrayList<string> clients;

    public ClientList() {
        this.clients = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addClient(String client) {
        this.clients.add(client);
    }

    public List<String> getClients() {
        // Note: Never give a reference to the internal objects of the class
        // as that means someone outside this class can own a reference to it
        // and can update the object without you knowing (by not going
        // through this class)
        Collections.unmodifiableList(this.clients);
    }
}
```

Comment: and return List<String>

Comment: Updated.  Though that seems like a very weird method - unless you are doing a Builder pattern...

Comment: that `ClientList` class looks like a valid solution to me but also if we go further and wanted to make it a threadSafe one then we'd have to do it abit differently. :)

Comment: @SergeyBenner totally :) But that was outside the scope of the question :)  I'll add a note that it isn't thread safe (for future Googlers)

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need to do:

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();

public void addClient(String name) {
    myList.add(name);
}
```

If you create a list inside the method, it will only have one value, and will go away once method execution finishes (unless it's returned). Have a look at different scopes [here](https://www.cs.umd.edu/~clin/MoreJava/Objects/local.html). You should create a list at a class level and add the elements into it.

Also, method does not need to return anything, so it's better to change the type to `void`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your approach is that everytime you call the method `addClient` a new ArrayList will be created.
I think this will work for you :

```
static ArrayList<String> myList;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    myList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public void addClient(String name){
    myList.add(name);             
}
```